# Что происходит с переменными со статической продолжительностью хранения при использовании DLL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, static

Скажите, пожалуйста, что произойдет, если в `DLL` будет находиться глобальная переменная, которая изменяется из экспортируемых функций?

Например:

```
int i{};

void One()
{
    ++i;
}

void Two()
{
    --i;
}
```

Я не совсем понимаю, будет ли переменная `i` общей для всех пользователей библиотеки (включая разные процессы), или же каждый, кто использует библиотеку (каждый процесс), получит свою собственную копию переменной `i`?

Comment: каждый процесс будет иметь свою копию.

Comment: добавлю к вышенаписанному: каждый процесс будет иметь не просто копию глобальную переменную, а копию в памяти всей загружаемой библиотеки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, разве происходит копирование самого исполняемого кода? Насколько мне известно, изначально разделяемые библиотеки предназначались именно для разделяемого использования как минимум кода, то есть - без копирования.

Comment: @MGNeo вы себе неправильно представляете процесс работы программы. Если просто, то разделяемые библиотеки (как и содержимое экзешника) грузится в оперативную память для использования. Так что библиотека то одна, она не копируется на диск, а загружается в память

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я не понимаю о чём вы, если библиотека есть, то её копия в памяти одна (секции `.text`, `.rodata` и возможно некоторые другие), копируется только `.data` (ну и подобные).

Comment: @MGNeo, она в секции `.data`, поэтому будет у каждого процесса своя.